# How do I add additional parameters to an ExtJS handler?

Tags: javascript, extjs, handler

I am using the ExtJS framework and I have the following handler that is used solely as a handler for a button:

```
var myButtonHandler = function(button, event){
   //code goes here
};
```

My button definition looks like this:

```
var myButton = new Ext.Button({
       id : 'myButton',
       renderTo : 'mybutton',
       text : 'Save',
       handler : myButtonHandler,
       scope : this
    });
```

As you can see, the handler receives the expected "button" and "event".  However, I'd like to pass some additional information into my handler.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would actually use Exts createDelegate prototype.

```
var appendBooleanOrInsertionIndex = 0; // Inserts the variables into the front of the function.
    appendBooleanOrInsertionIndex = true; // Appends the variables to the end of the arguments

var myButton = new Ext.Button({
   id : 'myButton',
   renderTo : 'mybutton',
   text : 'Save',
   handler : myButtonHandler.createDelegate(this, [param1, param2], appendBooleanOrInsertionIndex),
   scope : this
});
```

Comment: This is a more elegant answer than Seb's. The work of creating a wrapper is hidden by createDelegate.
Optionally, the user could add a custom property to the button and inspect that from the handler. I still prefer createDelegate.

Comment: So, how would you handle this inside of the **myButtonHandler** function to use your [params]? Just myButtonHandler([params])?

Comment: I went ahead and modified the example to better show what you can do with createDelegate. Also in Ext4 and SenchaTouch createDelegate has been moved out of the function prototype and is now accessible only by Ext.createDelegate(functionToDelegate, scope, args, appendOrInsertIndex)

Comment: hello i would like to have a clearer understanding about this. i've tried and it seems i stil don't get it.supposing

    `myButtonHandler.createDelegate(this, [param1, param2], appendBooleanOrInsertionIndex)`
where param1,param2 variables? if i want for example   
    ` myButtonHandler.createDelegate(this, ['title', 'author'], appendBooleanOrInsertionIndex)`
in 
    `mybuttonHandler(){
       //can i have this?
       alert(this.title);
     }
what will then be the value of title?
thanks
}`

Answer (score 5):

In Ext JS 4:

```
Ext.bind(myButtonHandler, this, [params array], true);
```

Comment: This is also true to ExtJS 3.4 (The use of Ext.createDelegate)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a good solution as Bradley has suggested. Here is an example.
Where repeatsStore - it is additional parameter that I want to pass to a button handler.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    name: 'panelBtn',
    layout: 'hbox',
    border: 0,
    items:[
        {xtype: 'button', text: 'Add', name:'addBtn',
         handler : Ext.bind(this.addBtnHandler, this, repeatsStore, true)
        }
    ]
});
```

And your handler should have three parameters - first two are standard, and last is your.

```
addBtnHandler:function(button, event, repeatsStore)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what is it that you want to pass, but using a wrapper could help:

```
var myButtonHandler = function (button, event, additionalData){
   //code goes here
};

var myButton = new Ext.Button({
  id : 'myButton',
  renderTo : 'mybutton',
  text : 'Save',
  handler : handlerWrapper,
  scope : this
});

var handlerWrapper = function (button, event){
  // Fetch additional data
  var additionalData = "whatever";
  myButtonHandler(button, event, additionalData);
};
```

Comment: I'm guessing "var handlerWrapper()" should be "function handlerWrapper()".  Yes?